# Gnome 3.8 (Ubuntu Gnome 13.04) won't start after boot. Where to look for logs of this kind?

Tags: 13.04, ubuntu-gnome

Until yesterday everything was going alright on Ubuntu GNOME 13.04 with GNOME 3.8 from gnome3-team ppa.

Today I cannot log in again. After booting, it hangs on the blue desktop from GDM and nothing happens.

I have just reinstalled Ubuntu GNOME keeping my home folder and once again the problem persists. Note that this time I didn't put any third parties PPAs.

Where to begin looking for solutions in this problem?
    `/var/log/boot.log` looks alright besides some kind of problem with 'saned' being disabled.

I found some errors in the syslog

```
Apr 23 20:52:14 marc-linux bluetoothd[960]: Bluetooth daemon 4.101
Apr 23 20:52:14 marc-linux bluetoothd[960]: Starting SDP server
Apr 23 20:52:14 marc-linux modem-manager[957]: <info>  ModemManager (version 0.6.0.0) starting...
Apr 23 20:52:14 marc-linux kernel: [   13.070853] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.16
Apr 23 20:52:14 marc-linux kernel: [   13.070874] NET: Registered protocol family 31
Apr 23 20:52:14 marc-linux kernel: [   13.070876] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
Apr 23 20:52:14 marc-linux kernel: [   13.070884] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
Apr 23 20:52:14 marc-linux kernel: [   13.070886] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
Apr 23 20:52:14 marc-linux kernel: [   13.070891] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
Apr 23 20:52:14 marc-linux kernel: [   13.111811] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
Apr 23 20:52:14 marc-linux kernel: [   13.111823] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
Apr 23 20:52:14 marc-linux kernel: [   13.111825] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
Apr 23 20:52:14 marc-linux bluetoothd[960]: DIS cannot start: GATT is disabled
Apr 23 20:52:14 marc-linux bluetoothd[960]: Failed to init deviceinfo plugin
Apr 23 20:52:14 marc-linux bluetoothd[960]: Failed to init proximity plugin
Apr 23 20:52:14 marc-linux bluetoothd[960]: Failed to init time plugin
Apr 23 20:52:14 marc-linux bluetoothd[960]: Failed to init alert plugin
Apr 23 20:52:14 marc-linux bluetoothd[960]: Failed to init thermometer plugin
Apr 23 20:52:14 marc-linux avahi-daemon[975]: Found user 'avahi' (UID 110) and group 'avahi' (GID 116).
Apr 23 20:52:14 marc-linux avahi-daemon[975]: Successfully dropped root privileges.
Apr 23 20:52:14 marc-linux avahi-daemon[975]: avahi-daemon 0.6.31 starting up.
Apr 23 20:52:15 marc-linux avahi-daemon[975]: Successfully called chroot().
Apr 23 20:52:15 marc-linux avahi-daemon[975]: Successfully dropped remaining capabilities.
Apr 23 20:52:15 marc-linux avahi-daemon[975]: Loading service file /services/udisks.service.
Apr 23 20:52:15 marc-linux kernel: [   13.231022] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
Apr 23 20:52:15 marc-linux kernel: [   13.231026] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
Apr 23 20:52:15 marc-linux kernel: [   13.231035] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
Apr 23 20:52:15 marc-linux avahi-daemon[975]: Network interface enumeration completed.
Apr 23 20:52:15 marc-linux avahi-daemon[975]: Registering HINFO record with values 'X86_64'/'LINUX'.
Apr 23 20:52:15 marc-linux avahi-daemon[975]: Server startup complete. Host name is marc-linux.local. Local service cookie is 2532208128.
Apr 23 20:52:15 marc-linux avahi-daemon[975]: Service "marc-linux" (/services/udisks.service) successfully established.
Apr 23 20:52:15 marc-linux kernel: [   13.301071] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
Apr 23 20:52:15 marc-linux bluetoothd[960]: Failed to init gatt_example plugin
Apr 23 20:52:15 marc-linux bluetoothd[960]: Bluetooth Management interface initialized
Apr 23 20:52:15 marc-linux kernel: [   13.460244] type=1400 audit(1366761135.314:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-pdf" pid=998 comm="apparmor_parser"
Apr 23 20:52:15 marc-linux kernel: [   13.460711] type=1400 audit(1366761135.314:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=998 comm="apparmor_parser"
Apr 23 20:52:15 marc-linux modem-manager[957]: <info>  Loaded plugin 'AnyData'
Apr 23 20:52:15 marc-linux modem-manager[957]: <info>  Loaded plugin 'Gobi'
Apr 23 20:52:15 marc-linux modem-manager[957]: <info>  Loaded plugin 'Wavecom'
Apr 23 20:52:15 marc-linux modem-manager[957]: <info>  Loaded plugin 'Linktop'
Apr 23 20:52:15 marc-linux modem-manager[957]: <info>  Loaded plugin 'Novatel'
Apr 23 20:52:15 marc-linux modem-manager[957]: <info>  Loaded plugin 'Ericsson MBM'
Apr 23 20:52:15 marc-linux modem-manager[957]: <info>  Loaded plugin 'Option'
Apr 23 20:52:15 marc-linux modem-manager[957]: <info>  Loaded plugin 'SimTech'
Apr 23 20:52:15 marc-linux modem-manager[957]: <info>  Loaded plugin 'MotoC'
Apr 23 20:52:15 marc-linux modem-manager[957]: <info>  Loaded plugin 'Longcheer'
Apr 23 20:52:15 marc-linux modem-manager[957]: <info>  Loaded plugin 'Nokia'
Apr 23 20:52:15 marc-linux modem-manager[957]: <info>  Loaded plugin 'Option High-Speed'
Apr 23 20:52:15 marc-linux modem-manager[957]: <info>  Loaded plugin 'Huawei'
Apr 23 20:52:15 marc-linux modem-manager[957]: <info>  Loaded plugin 'X22X'
Apr 23 20:52:15 marc-linux modem-manager[957]: <info>  Loaded plugin 'ZTE'
Apr 23 20:52:15 marc-linux modem-manager[957]: <info>  Loaded plugin 'Samsung'
Apr 23 20:52:15 marc-linux modem-manager[957]: <info>  Loaded plugin 'Sierra'
Apr 23 20:52:15 marc-linux modem-manager[957]: <info>  Loaded plugin 'Iridium'
Apr 23 20:52:15 marc-linux modem-manager[957]: <info>  Loaded plugin 'Cinterion'
Apr 23 20:52:15 marc-linux modem-manager[957]: <info>  Loaded plugin 'Generic'
Apr 23 20:52:15 marc-linux modem-manager[957]: <info>  Successfully loaded 20 plugins
Apr 23 20:52:15 marc-linux NetworkManager[1002]: <info> NetworkManager (version 0.9.8.0) is starting...
Apr 23 20:52:15 marc-linux NetworkManager[1002]: <info> Read config file /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
Apr 23 20:52:15 marc-linux NetworkManager[1002]: <info> WEXT support is enabled
Apr 23 20:52:16 marc-linux NetworkManager[1002]: <info> VPN: loaded org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.pptp
Apr 23 20:52:16 marc-linux NetworkManager[1002]: <info> DNS: loaded plugin dnsmasq
Apr 23 20:52:16 marc-linux dbus[946]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1' (using servicehelper)
Apr 23 20:52:16 marc-linux polkitd[1007]: started daemon version 0.105 using authority implementation `local' version `0.105'
Apr 23 20:52:16 marc-linux dbus[946]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1'
Apr 23 20:52:16 marc-linux NetworkManager[1002]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: init!
Apr 23 20:52:16 marc-linux NetworkManager[1002]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: update_system_hostname
Apr 23 20:52:16 marc-linux NetworkManager[1002]:    SCPluginIfupdown: management mode: unmanaged
Apr 23 20:52:16 marc-linux NetworkManager[1002]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices added (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/net/eth0, iface: eth0)
Apr 23 20:52:16 marc-linux NetworkManager[1002]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: device added (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/net/eth0, iface: eth0): no ifupdown configuration found.
Apr 23 20:52:16 marc-linux NetworkManager[1002]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/lo, iface: lo)
Apr 23 20:52:16 marc-linux NetworkManager[1002]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/lo, iface: lo): no ifupdown configuration found.
Apr 23 20:52:16 marc-linux NetworkManager[1002]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: end _init.
Apr 23 20:52:16 marc-linux NetworkManager[1002]: <info> Loaded plugin ifupdown: (C) 2008 Canonical Ltd.  To report bugs please use the NetworkManager mailing list.
Apr 23 20:52:16 marc-linux NetworkManager[1002]: <info> Loaded plugin keyfile: (c) 2007 - 2010 Red Hat, Inc.  To report bugs please use the NetworkManager mailing list.
Apr 23 20:52:16 marc-linux NetworkManager[1002]:    Ifupdown: get unmanaged devices count: 0
Apr 23 20:52:16 marc-linux NetworkManager[1002]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: (15700144) ... get_connections.
Apr 23 20:52:16 marc-linux NetworkManager[1002]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: (15700144) ... get_connections (managed=false): return empty list.
Apr 23 20:52:16 marc-linux NetworkManager[1002]:    Ifupdown: get unmanaged devices count: 0
Apr 23 20:52:16 marc-linux NetworkManager[1002]: <info> modem-manager is now available
Apr 23 20:52:16 marc-linux NetworkManager[1002]: <info> monitoring kernel firmware directory '/lib/firmware'.
Apr 23 20:52:16 marc-linux NetworkManager[1002]: <info> WiFi hardware radio set enabled
Apr 23 20:52:16 marc-linux NetworkManager[1002]: <info> WiFi enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
Apr 23 20:52:16 marc-linux NetworkManager[1002]: <info> WWAN enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
Apr 23 20:52:16 marc-linux NetworkManager[1002]: <info> WiMAX enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
Apr 23 20:52:16 marc-linux NetworkManager[1002]: <info> Networking is enabled by state file
Apr 23 20:52:16 marc-linux NetworkManager[1002]: <warn> failed to allocate link cache: (-10) Operation not supported
Apr 23 20:52:16 marc-linux NetworkManager[1002]: <info> (eth0): carrier is OFF
Apr 23 20:52:16 marc-linux NetworkManager[1002]: <info> (eth0): new Ethernet device (driver: 'forcedeth' ifindex: 2)
Apr 23 20:52:16 marc-linux NetworkManager[1002]: <info> (eth0): exported as /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/0
Apr 23 20:52:16 marc-linux NetworkManager[1002]: <info> (eth0): device state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed') [10 20 2]
Apr 23 20:52:16 marc-linux NetworkManager[1002]: <info> (eth0): bringing up device.
Apr 23 20:52:16 marc-linux NetworkManager[1002]: <info> (eth0): carrier now ON (device state 20)
Apr 23 20:52:16 marc-linux NetworkManager[1002]: <info> (eth0): preparing device.
Apr 23 20:52:16 marc-linux NetworkManager[1002]: <info> (eth0): deactivating device (reason 'managed') [2]
Apr 23 20:52:16 marc-linux kernel: [   14.588355] forcedeth 0000:00:07.0: irq 43 for MSI/MSI-X
Apr 23 20:52:16 marc-linux kernel: [   14.588386] forcedeth 0000:00:07.0 eth0: MSI enabled
Apr 23 20:52:16 marc-linux NetworkManager[1002]: <info> Added default wired connection 'Wired connection 1' for /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/net/eth0
Apr 23 20:52:16 marc-linux NetworkManager[1002]: <warn> /sys/devices/virtual/net/lo: couldn't determine device driver; ignoring...
Apr 23 20:52:16 marc-linux NetworkManager[1002]: <warn> /sys/devices/virtual/net/lo: couldn't determine device driver; ignoring...
Apr 23 20:52:16 marc-linux NetworkManager[1002]: <info> (eth0): device state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'none') [20 30 0]
Apr 23 20:52:16 marc-linux NetworkManager[1002]: <info> Auto-activating connection 'Wired connection 1'.
Apr 23 20:52:16 marc-linux NetworkManager[1002]: <info> Activation (eth0) starting connection 'Wired connection 1'
Apr 23 20:52:16 marc-linux NetworkManager[1002]: <info> (eth0): device state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
Apr 23 20:52:16 marc-linux NetworkManager[1002]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...
Apr 23 20:52:16 marc-linux NetworkManager[1002]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...
Apr 23 20:52:16 marc-linux NetworkManager[1002]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) scheduled...
Apr 23 20:52:16 marc-linux NetworkManager[1002]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
Apr 23 20:52:16 marc-linux NetworkManager[1002]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) starting...
Apr 23 20:52:16 marc-linux NetworkManager[1002]: <info> (eth0): device state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Apr 23 20:52:16 marc-linux NetworkManager[1002]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful.
Apr 23 20:52:16 marc-linux NetworkManager[1002]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) scheduled.
Apr 23 20:52:16 marc-linux NetworkManager[1002]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) complete.
Apr 23 20:52:16 marc-linux NetworkManager[1002]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) started...
Apr 23 20:52:16 marc-linux NetworkManager[1002]: <info> (eth0): device state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
Apr 23 20:52:16 marc-linux NetworkManager[1002]: <info> Activation (eth0) Beginning DHCPv4 transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Apr 23 20:52:16 marc-linux NetworkManager[1002]: <info> dhclient started with pid 1013
Apr 23 20:52:16 marc-linux NetworkManager[1002]: <info> Activation (eth0) Beginning IP6 addrconf.
Apr 23 20:52:16 marc-linux NetworkManager[1002]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) complete.
Apr 23 20:52:16 marc-linux dhclient: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.2.4
Apr 23 20:52:16 marc-linux dhclient: Copyright 2004-2012 Internet Systems Consortium.
Apr 23 20:52:16 marc-linux dhclient: All rights reserved.
Apr 23 20:52:16 marc-linux dhclient: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Apr 23 20:52:16 marc-linux dhclient: 
Apr 23 20:52:16 marc-linux NetworkManager[1002]: <info> (eth0): DHCPv4 state changed nbi -> preinit
Apr 23 20:52:16 marc-linux dhclient: Listening on LPF/eth0/00:26:2d:35:b9:04
Apr 23 20:52:16 marc-linux dhclient: Sending on   LPF/eth0/00:26:2d:35:b9:04
Apr 23 20:52:16 marc-linux dhclient: Sending on   Socket/fallback
Apr 23 20:52:16 marc-linux dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0xfc93b5d)
Apr 23 20:52:17 marc-linux kernel: [   15.366752] type=1400 audit(1366761137.222:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=1037 comm="apparmor_parser"
Apr 23 20:52:17 marc-linux kernel: [   15.367185] type=1400 audit(1366761137.222:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=1037 comm="apparmor_parser"
Apr 23 20:52:17 marc-linux kernel: [   15.367439] type=1400 audit(1366761137.222:12): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=1037 comm="apparmor_parser"
Apr 23 20:52:17 marc-linux kernel: [   15.389737] type=1400 audit(1366761137.246:13): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/telepathy/mission-control-5" pid=1040 comm="apparmor_parser"
Apr 23 20:52:17 marc-linux kernel: [   15.390275] type=1400 audit(1366761137.246:14): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/telepathy/telepathy-*" pid=1040 comm="apparmor_parser"
Apr 23 20:52:17 marc-linux kernel: [   15.391104] type=1400 audit(1366761137.246:15): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/telepathy/telepathy-*//sanitized_helper" pid=1040 comm="apparmor_parser"
Apr 23 20:52:17 marc-linux kernel: [   15.394550] type=1400 audit(1366761137.250:16): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-pdf" pid=1041 comm="apparmor_parser"
Apr 23 20:52:17 marc-linux kernel: [   15.395051] type=1400 audit(1366761137.250:17): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=1041 comm="apparmor_parser"
Apr 23 20:52:17 marc-linux anacron[1095]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2013-04-23
Apr 23 20:52:17 marc-linux acpid: starting up with proc fs
Apr 23 20:52:17 marc-linux cron[1078]: (CRON) INFO (pidfile fd = 3)
Apr 23 20:52:17 marc-linux anacron[1095]: Will run job `cron.daily' in 5 min.
Apr 23 20:52:17 marc-linux anacron[1095]: Will run job `cron.weekly' in 10 min.
Apr 23 20:52:17 marc-linux anacron[1095]: Will run job `cron.monthly' in 15 min.
Apr 23 20:52:17 marc-linux anacron[1095]: Jobs will be executed sequentially
Apr 23 20:52:17 marc-linux cron[1114]: (CRON) STARTUP (fork ok)
Apr 23 20:52:17 marc-linux cron[1114]: (CRON) INFO (Running @reboot jobs)
Apr 23 20:52:18 marc-linux avahi-daemon[975]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv6 with address fe80::226:2dff:fe35:b904.
Apr 23 20:52:18 marc-linux avahi-daemon[975]: New relevant interface eth0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Apr 23 20:52:18 marc-linux avahi-daemon[975]: Registering new address record for fe80::226:2dff:fe35:b904 on eth0.*.
Apr 23 20:52:18 marc-linux acpid: 33 rules loaded
Apr 23 20:52:18 marc-linux acpid: waiting for events: event logging is off
Apr 23 20:52:18 marc-linux acpid: client connected from 1265[0:0]
Apr 23 20:52:18 marc-linux acpid: 1 client rule loaded
Apr 23 20:52:19 marc-linux dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.25.7 on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0xfc93b5d)
Apr 23 20:52:19 marc-linux dhclient: DHCPOFFER of 192.168.25.7 from 192.168.25.1
Apr 23 20:52:19 marc-linux dhclient: DHCPACK of 192.168.25.7 from 192.168.25.1
Apr 23 20:52:19 marc-linux NetworkManager[1002]: <info> (eth0): DHCPv4 state changed preinit -> bound
Apr 23 20:52:19 marc-linux NetworkManager[1002]: <info>   address 192.168.25.7
Apr 23 20:52:19 marc-linux NetworkManager[1002]: <info>   prefix 24 (255.255.255.0)
Apr 23 20:52:19 marc-linux NetworkManager[1002]: <info>   gateway 192.168.25.1
Apr 23 20:52:19 marc-linux NetworkManager[1002]: <info>   hostname 'marc-linux'
Apr 23 20:52:19 marc-linux NetworkManager[1002]: <info>   nameserver '192.168.25.1'
Apr 23 20:52:19 marc-linux NetworkManager[1002]: <info>   domain name 'home'
Apr 23 20:52:19 marc-linux NetworkManager[1002]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 5 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Commit) scheduled...
Apr 23 20:52:19 marc-linux NetworkManager[1002]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 5 of 5 (IPv4 Commit) started...
Apr 23 20:52:19 marc-linux avahi-daemon[975]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv4 with address 192.168.25.7.
Apr 23 20:52:19 marc-linux avahi-daemon[975]: New relevant interface eth0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Apr 23 20:52:19 marc-linux avahi-daemon[975]: Registering new address record for 192.168.25.7 on eth0.IPv4.
Apr 23 20:52:19 marc-linux dhclient: bound to 192.168.25.7 -- renewal in 39834 seconds.
Apr 23 20:52:19 marc-linux gdm-simple-slave[1168]: WARNING: Failed to give slave programs access to the display. Trying to proceed.
Apr 23 20:52:19 marc-linux dbus[946]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.Accounts' (using servicehelper)
Apr 23 20:52:19 marc-linux accounts-daemon[1297]: started daemon version 0.6.29
Apr 23 20:52:19 marc-linux dbus[946]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.Accounts'
Apr 23 20:52:19 marc-linux dbus[946]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit' (using servicehelper)
Apr 23 20:52:19 marc-linux dbus[946]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit'
Apr 23 20:52:20 marc-linux gdm-launch-environment][1294]: GLib-CRITICAL: g_variant_compare: assertion `!g_variant_is_container (a)' failed
Apr 23 20:52:20 marc-linux gdm-launch-environment][1294]: GLib-CRITICAL: g_variant_compare: assertion `!g_variant_is_container (a)' failed
Apr 23 20:52:20 marc-linux NetworkManager[1002]: <info> (eth0): device state change: ip-config -> secondaries (reason 'none') [70 90 0]
Apr 23 20:52:20 marc-linux NetworkManager[1002]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 5 of 5 (IPv4 Commit) complete.
Apr 23 20:52:20 marc-linux NetworkManager[1002]: <info> (eth0): device state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none') [90 100 0]
Apr 23 20:52:20 marc-linux NetworkManager[1002]: <info> Policy set 'Wired connection 1' (eth0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.
Apr 23 20:52:20 marc-linux NetworkManager[1002]: <info> DNS: starting dnsmasq...
Apr 23 20:52:20 marc-linux NetworkManager[1002]: <warn> dnsmasq not available on the bus, can't update servers.
Apr 23 20:52:20 marc-linux NetworkManager[1002]: <error> [1366761140.496992] [nm-dns-dnsmasq.c:402] update(): dnsmasq owner not found on bus: Could not get owner of name 'org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.dnsmasq': no such name
Apr 23 20:52:20 marc-linux NetworkManager[1002]: <warn> DNS: plugin dnsmasq update failed
Apr 23 20:52:20 marc-linux NetworkManager[1002]: <info> Writing DNS information to /sbin/resolvconf
Apr 23 20:52:20 marc-linux dnsmasq[1429]: started, version 2.65 cache disabled
Apr 23 20:52:20 marc-linux dnsmasq[1429]: compile time options: IPv6 GNU-getopt DBus i18n IDN DHCP DHCPv6 no-Lua TFTP conntrack
Apr 23 20:52:20 marc-linux dnsmasq[1429]: DBus support enabled: connected to system bus
Apr 23 20:52:20 marc-linux dnsmasq[1429]: warning: no upstream servers configured
Apr 23 20:52:20 marc-linux NetworkManager[1002]: <info> Activation (eth0) successful, device activated.
Apr 23 20:52:20 marc-linux dbus[946]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' (using servicehelper)
Apr 23 20:52:20 marc-linux NetworkManager[1002]: <warn> dnsmasq appeared on DBus: :1.20
Apr 23 20:52:20 marc-linux NetworkManager[1002]: <info> Writing DNS information to /sbin/resolvconf
Apr 23 20:52:20 marc-linux dnsmasq[1429]: setting upstream servers from DBus
Apr 23 20:52:20 marc-linux dnsmasq[1429]: using nameserver 192.168.25.1#53
Apr 23 20:52:20 marc-linux dbus[946]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Apr 23 20:52:22 marc-linux dbus[946]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.UPower' (using servicehelper)
Apr 23 20:52:22 marc-linux dbus[946]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.UPower'
Apr 23 20:52:23 marc-linux gdm-launch-environment][1294]: GLib-CRITICAL: g_variant_compare: assertion `!g_variant_is_container (a)' failed
Apr 23 20:52:23 marc-linux gdm-launch-environment][1294]: GLib-CRITICAL: g_variant_compare: assertion `!g_variant_is_container (a)' failed
Apr 23 20:52:23 marc-linux dbus[946]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.RealtimeKit1' (using servicehelper)
Apr 23 20:52:23 marc-linux dbus[946]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.RealtimeKit1'
Apr 23 20:52:23 marc-linux rtkit-daemon[1746]: Successfully called chroot.
Apr 23 20:52:23 marc-linux rtkit-daemon[1746]: Successfully dropped privileges.
Apr 23 20:52:23 marc-linux rtkit-daemon[1746]: Successfully limited resources.
Apr 23 20:52:23 marc-linux rtkit-daemon[1746]: Running.
Apr 23 20:52:23 marc-linux rtkit-daemon[1746]: Watchdog thread running.
Apr 23 20:52:23 marc-linux rtkit-daemon[1746]: Canary thread running.
Apr 23 20:52:23 marc-linux rtkit-daemon[1746]: Successfully made thread 1744 of process 1744 (n/a) owned by '114' high priority at nice level -11.
Apr 23 20:52:23 marc-linux rtkit-daemon[1746]: Supervising 1 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Apr 23 20:52:24 marc-linux rtkit-daemon[1746]: Successfully made thread 1753 of process 1744 (n/a) owned by '114' RT at priority 5.
Apr 23 20:52:24 marc-linux rtkit-daemon[1746]: Supervising 2 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Apr 23 20:52:24 marc-linux rtkit-daemon[1746]: Successfully made thread 1754 of process 1744 (n/a) owned by '114' RT at priority 5.
Apr 23 20:52:24 marc-linux rtkit-daemon[1746]: Supervising 3 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Apr 23 20:52:24 marc-linux rtkit-daemon[1746]: Successfully made thread 1755 of process 1744 (n/a) owned by '114' RT at priority 5.
Apr 23 20:52:24 marc-linux rtkit-daemon[1746]: Supervising 4 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Apr 23 20:52:24 marc-linux rtkit-daemon[1746]: Successfully made thread 1757 of process 1757 (n/a) owned by '114' high priority at nice level -11.
Apr 23 20:52:24 marc-linux rtkit-daemon[1746]: Supervising 5 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
Apr 23 20:52:24 marc-linux pulseaudio[1757]: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
Apr 23 20:52:25 marc-linux dbus[946]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.UDisks2' (using servicehelper)
Apr 23 20:52:25 marc-linux udisksd[1766]: udisks daemon version 2.1.0 starting
Apr 23 20:52:25 marc-linux dbus[946]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.UDisks2'
Apr 23 20:52:25 marc-linux udisksd[1766]: Acquired the name org.freedesktop.UDisks2 on the system message bus
Apr 23 20:52:26 marc-linux gnome-session[1424]: WARNING: Detected that screensaver has left the bus
Apr 23 20:52:27 marc-linux gnome-session[1424]: WARNING: Detected that screensaver has left the bus
Apr 23 20:52:27 marc-linux gnome-session[1424]: WARNING: App 'gnome-shell.desktop' respawning too quickly
Apr 23 20:52:27 marc-linux gnome-session[1424]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
Apr 23 20:52:29 marc-linux ntpdate[1553]: adjust time server 91.189.94.4 offset -0.339355 sec
Apr 23 20:52:36 marc-linux NetworkManager[1002]: <info> (eth0): IP6 addrconf timed out or failed.
Apr 23 20:52:36 marc-linux NetworkManager[1002]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) scheduled...
Apr 23 20:52:36 marc-linux NetworkManager[1002]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) started...
Apr 23 20:52:36 marc-linux NetworkManager[1002]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) complete.
Apr 23 20:57:17 marc-linux anacron[1095]: Job `cron.daily' started
Apr 23 20:57:17 marc-linux anacron[2274]: Updated timestamp for job `cron.daily' to 2013-04-23
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Check `syslog, Xorg.0.log, dmesg`, you can find them in `/var/log`.

Comment: I found some errors on the syslog and edited my question

Comment: Did you remove the third party PPAs?

Comment: Try to remove the gnome-shell-extensions package, if it doesn't bring you forward, reinstall the `gnome-shell, gnome-session, gdm, compiz, compiz-core, metacity` packages. Xorg.0.log did not show any errors?

Comment: I did a clean installation and the problem persists. I will try reinstalling all those packages once in home

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I too made the mistake of not using `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and could not log in.

Fortunately, there is a way to apply the full update without reinstalling Ubuntu. When you restart your computer and you think the booting process is done, press `Ctrl+Alt+F1`. You will be prompted a command line.

Log in with your username and password and make sure you have internet connection (e.g. `ping google.com`). If your WiFi isn't working, connect your computer to the router using an ethernet cable.

You can then simply type `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and your machine will download and install the missing packages. Restart your computer with `sudo shutdown -r now` and after rebooting, Gnome 3.8 should be working just fine.

Comment: That worked after doing a dist-upgrade to the stable 13.04 version out yesterday. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I notice you mention you have installed the gnome3 PPA. Did you ensure that while installing this PPA you performed an update with: `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` as opposed to just using the `upgrade` option? This is mentioned in the release notes of the PPA and if it is not done it will cause symptoms similar to what you describe.

Comment: Yes, I did a distupgrade