# Text-only login after 13.10 upgrade

Tags: graphics, login

After upgrading from 13.04 to 13.10 I no longer get the GUI login. After I login I can run `startx` and the GUI login eventually comes up. How do I get the GUI login back by default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently if I just wait long enough, the GUI login comes up.

Answer (score -1):

I think you forgot the `dist-upgrade` and created inter-process communication irregularities. On a terminal, use :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
# And just to make it clean :
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

For more info : [Gnome 3.8 (Ubuntu Gnome 13.04) won't start after boot. Where to look for logs of this kind?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/284766/gnome-3-8-ubuntu-gnome-13-04-wont-start-after-boot-where-to-look-for-logs-of)

(don't hesitate to give share logs, see previous link)

Comment: That question and top answer were people who couldn't log in. I said I can log in via text-only login. Also, had already done dist-upgrade.